# iframe.height(100); is adding in chrome, and setting in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var iframe = $("#id_iframe");
iframe.height(200);
```

in chrome, this is adding to the current height instead of replacing the current height.

in firefox, it is replacing which is right.

What do I need?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
iframe.css('height', '200px');
```